# Angular routing not working in case of nested routes

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router

I have an application. When one opens the application, then there is a login page. After successful login, you land on home page which has a side menu. With side menu, home page loads a default content. Now the issue is when I reload the application and clicks Assignment, it works fine and loads `/base/home/assignments`. Or if I click batches, it works fine and loads `/base/home/batches`. The problem is when you are on any of these pages `assignments` or `batches`, and click the other one, it doesn't take you to that page and neither gives any error. I am confused as what did I do wrong. Following is my routing -

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes, RouteReuseStrategy } from '@angular/router';
import { BasePage } from './base.page';
import { HomePage } from './home-page/home.page';
import { DashBoardPage } from './dashboard/dashboard.page';
import { AssignmentsPage } from './assignnments/assignments.page';
import { AddAssignmentsPage } from './assignnments/add/add-assignment.page';
import { ViewAssignmentsPage } from './assignnments/view/view-assignment.page';
import { AddBatchPage } from './batches/add/add-batch.page';
import { BatchesPage } from './batches/batches.page';

const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: 'home',
        component: HomePage,
        children: [
            {
                path: 'assignments',
                component: AssignmentsPage,
                children: [
                    {
                        path: 'view',
                        component: ViewAssignmentsPage,
                    },
                    {
                        path: 'add',
                        component: AddAssignmentsPage,
                    },
                    {
                        path: '',
                        component: AddAssignmentsPage,
                    },
                ],
            },
            {
                path: 'batches',
                component: BatchesPage,
                children: [
                    {
                        path: 'view',
                        component: ViewBatchPage,
                    },
                    {
                        path: 'add',
                        component: AddBatchPage,
                    },
                    {
                        path: '',
                        component: AddBatchPage,
                    },
                ],
            },
            {
                path: '', // child route path, to default load dashboard when home is openened from base component
                component: DashBoardPage, // child route component that the router renders
            },
        ],
    },

    {
        path: '',
        component: BasePage,
    },
];

@NgModule({
    imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
    exports: [RouterModule],
    providers: [],
})
export class BasePageRoutingModule {}
```

It works only once - like I am able to go from `assignments` to `batches` pages but nothing after that.

Comment: you should provide an absolute path

Comment: where? do you mean I shouldn't use child routes?

Comment: on nav redirect html use routerLink="/home/assignments"

Comment: In your RouterModule.forRoot(), enter the option `enableTracing: true` and then look in the browser console for clues for what's going on.

Comment: It says `Cannot find name 'enableTracing'`

Comment: @RolstanD'souza, I was able to solve it the way you suggested. Using `/base/home/assignments` instead of `/assignments` works. Thanks.

Comment: @a-p RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { enableTracing: true })